# Have any one use this rails event_calender plug in to show events with the holidays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

How can I put event with regarding holidays. Do any one have experience with this??
I need to create event which may have holiday at the middle of that and event should not be visible in that holiday period.
Can any one know how to do this ??
[event_calendar plug in link at git hub](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar)

Comment: hear some of screen shots of the event calendar plug-in http://dev.elevationblog.com/2009/7/23/event-calendar-rails-plugin/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does any one work with the rails “calendar_date_select” plugin??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896165/does-any-one-work-with-the-rails-calendar-date-select-plugin)

Comment: Why do you ask the same question three times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add holidays in to calendar. There is way to add holidays in to rails event calendar plug in as new event but there is problem arise when holidays comes to middle of the particular event.